# Moving a file in Eclipse breaks the program - any way to solve that?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

All,

I'm a beginner user of Eclipse.  I am currently using it for a PHP project.  I am starting to have a lot of PHP files under my project so I created a folder inside the project to relocate some of the files.  However this breaks the program because as I move the files the functions calling for those files are not updated to reflect their new location.

Is there a way to do that automatically in Eclipse?  I would have thought that it would be a core functionality (but then again, I've never used an IDE before.)

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: No, you can't do that without refactoring the code. A global find/replace could fix the problem for you though.

Comment: @Matt - If you enter that below, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that without refactoring the code. A global find/replace could fix the problem for you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete your .metadata directory.
(after backup)

```
/YourProjectDirectory/.metadata
```

And restart your IDE.

Or eventualy try to run eclipse with the param "-clean"

`"C:\ecplipse.exe -clean"` (from CMD)